Claude premium vs chatgpt premium for self-learning computer science subjects?
This is how I plan to study:

get a textbook

attempt its exercises

read the contents to solve exercises

when stuck, first google for 1 hour. If still answer not found, youtube for 1 hour. Take a break for an hour from the subject. Then go to AI tools.

Do programming projects. When stuck, google/youtube for 3 hours. Take a break from the subject. Ask AI tools to help.


Now, I am really torn out between chatgpt and claude (Or anything else) will be useful for self-tutoring. I really wanted to do MS in CS in University but turns out it's a full time course and I can't leave my current full time job.

+1 seems like a good approach, especially leaving AI tools as a last resort (but with reservations even then, see my answer for details).  If possible having a study group or someone else you can talk to or ask for advice is likely to be better than AI tools (as they can judge better how to be "helpfully unhelpful" and give hints rather than just explain).  Also sometimes you will be able to improve your understanding by helping them.

What is the question here exactly? Is it between Claude premium and ChatGPT premium specifically, or are you asking to what extent you should use AI in general in your workflow? The title and post body seem largely unrelated. Googling for a fixed time, say, 1 hour seems rather arbitrary. If I can't find a solution on Google in 5 minutes, generally, another 55 minutes won't yield an answer. You can do OMSCS part time, 1 class per semester.

Googling for things and getting ChatGPT to help you when you are stuck can make it difficult to learn problem solving skills, which is the hardest and most important skill in programming.  Likewise the ability to work things out and understand things without them being explained to you (not just programming - this applies to a wide range of CS problems).  Your sub-conscious is great at working things out, so if you get stuck go work on something else for a while and come back to the problem - at the very least you will be looking at it with fresh eyes.  Just mark the problem as unfinished and go onto the next one if you have been stuck for an hour, as your programming skills improve you can go back to the unfinished questions and you will probably find they don't present a problem any more.
I've been teaching programming for over 30 years, and I have seen how this (the increase in on-line tutorials and solutions to problems, but more recently AI/ML tools) has changed the learning environment for students over that time.  The coding aspect of programming has got easier and students find it easier to get things done, but problem solving, debugging, understanding API documentation and understanding other peoples code have all become more difficult for students.  Sadly those are the skills likely to be most required by professional programmers in an industrial environment with AI tools.
I often say that using ChatGPT for learning programming is a lot like going to the gym and watching other people pump iron and wondering why your muscles are not getting any bigger.  Every time ChatGPT solves a problem for you, you have missed an opportunity to work on your problem solving strength, you have just watched someone else doing the problem solving for you.  What you want is a spotter, who gives you just enough assistance to complete that last "rep" of your bench press.  ChatGPT is far too helpful if you let it.
ChatGPT is great for competent programmers who already understand what they are doing (and more importantly can critically evaluate the code generated by ChatGPT) to reduce the effort of generating boilerplate code.  It isn't a good tool for learning.  So I am not saying don't use ChatGPT, just use it as a spotter (try asking it to give you a hint rather than an explanation?).

I’m in a similar boat, though I’m already a computer science student. Honestly, I would go with ChatGPT for learning—it’s been way more engaging and fun for me than the usual boring lectures. 
I like how I can just ask ChatGPT to explain complex concepts, debug code, or even help me understand tough exercises. It feels like having a personal tutor that’s always ready to dive deep and make things clearer, at my own pace. Plus, the interactive nature keeps it much more exciting than just reading a textbook.
Claude is great for other tasks, but when it comes to diving into computer science, ChatGPT has really been a game changer for me. I’m sure it’ll work wonders for you too
